# How do I upgrade the encryption on my IIS-exported pfx file?

Tags: pkcs12, pfx

Having found out [what encryption algorithm was used to encrypt my pfx file, using openssl](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/152866/which-encryption-algorithm-is-used-in-password-protected-pfx-pkcs-12-certifica), I now want to upgrade the pfx file to use the most secure algorithms available, rather than 40-bit rc2. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Openssl can also be used to upgrade the encryption, by creating a new pfx file with the same certificate and private key, but seems to require a multi-step process

First read the pfx file and export it as a pem file:

```
openssl pkcs12 -in badcert.pfx -passin pass:SECRETPASSWORD -nodes -out temp.pem
```

Second read the pem file and export it as a pfx file with upgraded encryption. I included the `-macalg sha256` option here, though I can't prove that it is doing anything:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in temp.pem -out goodcert.pfx -descert -passout pass:SECRETPASSWORD -macalg sha256
```

Verify that the new pfx file has good (or at least better) encryption:

```
openssl pkcs12 -info -in goodcert.pfx -noout -passin pass:SECRETPASSWORD
```

Delete the old files:

```
rm temp.pem
rm badcert.pfx
```

Note that although openssl reports password-based encryption with SHA-1, it is actually the PBKDF2 variant of iterated SHA-1, per [RFC7292](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7292), so this is not a weakness.