# What are the recommended scrypt cost factors for 2016?

Tags: passwords, hash, password-management, scrypt

I've been trying to look for the answer, but the latest one I found was outdated by three years. So what are the recommended scrypt cost factors for 2016?

Comment: The recommended cost factors = "Use Argon2"?

Comment: What? I'm not sure I understand what you're saying.

Comment: Not sure if this'd be the correct thought process, but I'd think to use moore's law and assume that since 2^3 = 8, so at least 8x the 2013 estimates you found.

Comment: Moore's law is to do with transistors on a chip, not with the speed of computation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In general, use the maximum cost factor that is bearable from a performance perspective. I would create a benchmark application which is as close as possible to what your application does, and find out the cost factor *on your production hardware* that gives you the maximum tolerable delay.

In most systems, I strive for a 10 to 20 ms delay. Assume your attacker has hardware that is, say, 1000 times more powerful than yours (which is not unreasonable, given that scrypt cannot be GPU-accelerated), he can try 10<sup>5</sup> guesses per second. For a 10-character alphanumeric password, that's 26<sup>10</sup> passwords, or about 10<sup>14</sup> potential guesses. That would take 10<sup>9</sup> seconds, or 31 years. Sounds acceptable to me.

If you want to use even higher delays, remember that `scrypt` is memory hard. This means it uses a (relative) lot of memory, in the order of megabytes, for each verification, so having a lot of them running in parallel might be more of a performance hit than the absolute processing power required.

Have a look at [Security.stackexchange.com "Recommended # of iterations when using PKBDF2-SHA256?"](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/3993/115250) for a good analysis of the same subject on PBKDF2.