# Increase password iterations?

Tags: passwords, hash, password-cracking, macos

Is it possible to strengthen the macOS login password by [increasing the number of sha-512](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3959/recommended-of-iterations-when-using-pkbdf2-sha256) iterations?

Comment: If you meant to ask "how do I...?" rather than "can I...?", you may get better answers over on [apple.se], our sister site specializing in Apple products.

Comment: Possibly related: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/340202/how-to-harden-user-login-password